# Is there a way for a column to be a foreign key/refer of multiple tables according to a value of another column

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I am trying to do something like having a table of customers who can choose from multiple payment methods, each payment method may require different credentials and codes.

The payment methods are reflected in payment_method. Lets say if payment method is A then, then the customer id should reference table A , if it is B then it references B and so on ...

For example customer of customer_id 123 has chosen "Cashapp"
then there should be a record in customers_cashapp table with an id of 123. Is this constraint possilbe in mysql

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear to me how you intend to use the table with the fk constraints, but it seems very likely you can design your database in a better way.  That said, you can accomplish this using constraints on generated columns:

```
create table customers_payment_method (
customer_id int not null,
payment_method varbinary(8),
customer_id_cashapp int as
  (case payment_method when 'cashapp' then customer_id end) stored,
customer_id_paypal int as
  (case payment_method when 'paypal' then customer_id end) stored,
constraint cidcashapp foreign key (customer_id_cashapp) references customers_cashapp(customer_id),
constraint cidpaypal foreign key (customer_id_paypal) references customers_paypal(customer_id)
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Ffls4NG)

Comment: That's a clever way to bypass the restriction. But it might prove to be tedious to alter the customer_payment_method table every time a new payment method is added or an existing one is discontinued to stay tuned. And I suppose it might be tricky to write a query which needs to join the customer_payment_table and the payment table, as we don't know which payment table to join until we see which method is used, unless an INNER JOIN for each method table separated by UNION is used.  Perhaps the OP should consider combining all the payment method tables into one single table : )

Comment: @blabla_bingo they are already creating a new table for each payment method they want constrainted, so adding an additional constraint isn't that tedious.   agree that the design is bad, but hard to know how to advise without knowing a whole lot more about their usage.

Comment: instead of this solution is it possible to store ids in 1 column only  "customer_payment_method_id"  which references either cashapp or paypal according to the value of payment_method

so if the payment method is cashapp then it will have cidcashapp reference constraint

Comment: Yes, though if you want a foreign key constraint on it you would do exactly like this answer (set up a generated column for each payment method and put the constraint on that).  Note that generated columns don't have to be set by you, it happens automatically.